# Почему не работает log4j на Servelet? Не создается файл?

Tags: java, servlet, tomcat

Логирование отлично работает в обычных приложениях, нормально сохраняет в директорию файлик с логами, но абсолютно не хочет этого делать в приложении на Servelet, не создается файл с логами совершенно.

```
`import com.sun.java.accessibility.util.TopLevelWindowListener;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by Loligan on 06.04.2016.
 */
public class One extends HttpServlet{
    {
        Two.setLog("started");
    }
    static {
        Two.setLog("connect");
    }
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Two.setLog("msg");
        super.doGet(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Two.setLog("msg");
        super.doPost(req, resp);
    }
}

class Two{
    {
        setLog("started");
    }
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(One.class);
    public static void setLog(String msg){
        log.info(msg);
    }
}
```

Файл конфигурации

```
   # Уровень логирования
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file

# Апендер для работы с файлами
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
# Путь где будет создаваться лог файл
log4j.appender.file.File=src//java//og_file.log
# Указываем максимальный размер файла с логами
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
# Конфигурируем шаблон вывода логов в файл
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Файл по идее должен сохранятся в src/main/java но не сохраняет. В проекте его просто нету. Использую IDEA

Comment: абсолютный путь к файлу попробуйте указать, типа `c:\\tmp\\file.log` или там `/tmp/file.log`

Comment: Потому что Logger.getLogger(One.class); подставляет сервер. Подставляет он свой собственный логгер. Вам нужно по-другому установить Logger log. Или настроить серверный, чтобы для Ваших класов писал в отдельный файл

Comment: Пробывал уже. Не помогло

Comment: Sergey например как переделать? А то я не понимаю кажется

Comment: Я не знаю как. Знаю только, что Logger в таком виде выдаёт системный (т.е. серверный) логгер. С другой стороны запись ведётся в системный лог, если фильтры пропускают. И не надо возиться с собственным логом. Уровень info вроде всегда пропускается.

Comment: Попробывал логирование tomact но тоже не работает.